# start app automatically at some time on jailbreak IOS devices

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I have created an iOS application and one of the new features that the client wants me to add is -

> if the app is in the background and the user does not touch the device's
>   screen for 60 seconds, START THE APP AGAIN.

I have searched and found this article: http://n8henrie.com/2012/07/scheduling-ios-apps/
but this is not very helpful,  because I must achieve this task programatically. The app will run on 200 devices, and I can't do those steps with each one.

Any ideas?

**IMPORTANT**: I'm willing to jailbreak the device if it is not possible is some other way.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Is the 60 seconds a firm time period?  Or, is that configurable?  In Settings, users can choose when to let the device auto-lock.  1 minute is one possible setting for this.  Can you restart the app on auto-lock, or does it have to be "if the user does not touch the device's screen for 60 seconds"?  Is this only when the user is on the Home screen, or if they're running another app, but don't touch the screen, should you **then** also restart your app?  What about when the screen is locked?  Does the 60 second auto-restart rule still apply then?

Comment: Yes, when the user does not touch the screen for 60 seconds I must start the app again. I mean even if the app is on the foreground and then it goes background, i must again count 60 sec since user's last touch on the device and start it again...If the user is in another app...well he touches the screen there also, no? When the screen is locked the rule does not apply. Hope its clear now...

Comment: No, not necessarily.  What if the other app is playing video?  The user might very well not touch the screen for 60 seconds.  Is your app supposed to activate then?

Comment: Excepting the video case, do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, but I need to know how it's supposed to work.  You have to narrow down the requirements first, before you pick some technique that's not going to work some of the time.

Comment: If it plays a movie, I should open the app only after the movies is finished. If the user just touches the home screen, then the app should be opened after the setteled time. Or if it opens an application(excepting a video) in the foreground, but there is no user touch for x seconds, my application should come in front. Please tell me some hints or how should I make it work, because I don't have the slightest idea. Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31625/discussion-between-adrian-and-nate)